# Completion in edebug-eval-expression

Tags: debugging, completion, edebug

Is there a way to get completion-at-point to work inside `edebug-eval-expression` (i.e. similarly to the way it works in `eval-expression`)?  Presently, when I press <kbd>tab</kbd> inside of a call to `edebug-eval-expression`, there are no completion candidates despite <kbd>tab</kbd> being bound to `completion-at-point`.

This behavior occurs even in vanilla Emacs 25.3.1 without any configuration.  Does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: I suggest you report this as a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for that behavior is simply that different `interactive` forms are used in `edebug-eval-expression` and `eval-expression`.
You can just override the interactive form of `edebug-eval-expression` with a part of the interactive form of `eval-expression`.
(Direct replacement of the interactive form does not work since that two functions differ in the number of arguments.)

```el
(defun lispTZA-edebug-eval-expression-completion (expr)
  "Replace interactive-spec of `edebug-eval-expression'
with `read--expression' from `eval-expression' to get completion working."
  (interactive (list (read--expression "Eval: "))))

(advice-add 'edebug-eval-expression :before #'lispTZA-edebug-eval-expression-completion)
```